# The Dropend Menu in Bootstrap Not Working Correctly When Dropdown Menu Used

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a sidebar with Bootstrap 5 and using a "Dropdown" and "Dropend" menu using the respective Bootstrap classes.

My issue is when the Dropdown menu is open, the Dropend menu is not positioned correctly. Instead of being immediately to the right of the menu icon, there is a big gap (seemingly the size of the dropdown width). When the Dropdown menu, is closed it works fine.

See two images below. The first one shows the proper alignment with it immediately to the right. The second shows the issue when the Dropdown menu is open and the big gap.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>My Example</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link xhref="designs/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        /* added this so that the dropdown menu would stay on top of content in the main area. */
        .not-bs-sidebar {
            z-index: 9999; 
        }
        /* added so the main area fills the page width. */
        .not-bs-main {
            flex: 1; 
        }
        /* set the size of the sidebar. */
        .not-bs-sidebar.active {
            width: 80px; 
        }
        /* the rest is optional basic styling. */
        .not-bs-sidebar .nav-link {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            padding-left: 0px; 
        }
        .not-bs-sidebar.active .not-bs-dropdown-menu {
            background-color: white; 
            border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        }
        .not-bs-sidebar.active .not-bs-dropdown-menu a {
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 bg-primary not-bs-sidebar active" id="sidebar">
                <div class="not-bs-sidebar-frame d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3">
                    <div class="not-bs-sidebar-nav">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="default.aspx" class="nav-link"><i class="bi bi-house"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="bi bi-speedometer2"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dropdown-example" role="button"><i class="bi bi-table"></i></a>
                                <div class="collapse not-bs-dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-example">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some other action here</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="bi bi-grid"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropend">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="bi bi-table"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 not-bs-main" id="main">
                <div class="row not-bs-body">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="bg-body-tertiary border rounded p-3">
                            <h2>Page Conent</h2>
                            <div style="height: 400px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

It appears the reason this is happening is because the widths of all the "li" tags in the navigation are expanding when the dropdown menu is open. So, the dropend menu is opening at the edge of the expanded "li". I added two more images with red borders around the "li" tags to demonstrate.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FROM

```
<div class="collapse not-bs-dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-example">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some other action here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

TO

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some Another action here</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hm. That didn't work. I added the "margin-left: 69px;" to the class you suggested and that only moved the first dropdown over and still the gap exists with the dropend menu. But now it's farther to the right and the gap is bigger.

Comment: Hi, maybe you should add the margin-left to the other class that is connected with the first Dropdown that is shown on the second picture, maybe I chose the wrong class….

Comment: That doesn't work eighter. I edited my example with more information and images. It looks like this is happening because all the "li" tags are expanding when the dropdown menu is expanding.

Comment: I edited my answer try the code again.

Comment: That changes the nature of my menu. I don't want it to be a popup version of a dropdown. I want it to be a collapsible version of a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions to my problem.

**Solution 1:**

The first solution is to set the width of "li" tag for the "dropend" menu item that has the issue. In this case, I set the width to desired width as shown below.

**Code:**

```
<li class="nav-item dropend" style="width: 48.875px;">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="bi bi-table"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Solution 2:**

The second solution is to change the bootstrap class that is being used with the "dropend" menu item that has the issue. Instead of using the bootstrap class "nav-link", use bootstrap class "btn-group". Interestingly, the width of the associated "li" tag still stretches, however, the "btn-group" class ignores it. If you investigate the differences between the two classes I assume you'll figure out the difference as to why. But, for now... this works.

**Code:**

```
<li class="btn-group dropend">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="bi bi-table"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Well done Sir